# Remember scroll bar position in the HTML/CSS table

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table, position

Could somebody help me to get this working?  I suppose I need to use JS for this, but I have very little experience with it... so I think some code sample could be useful. I got simple table like this (for simplification I didn't copied content of table, because its a lot of code and not relevant.

```
<div style="overflow:auto; height:600px; border:2px solid black; border-radius:5px; background:white">
<table style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse">
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: This has very little context. Not sure what table nor scroll bar you are talking about. Post some code if you want help. Sorry this is just really vague. A link would be ok too.

Comment: Sorry...Question updated...I cannot provide link, but at least I copied how my simplified table looks like.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery (this will save a cookie with the scroll position):

```
// When document is ready...
$(document).ready(function() {

    // If cookie is set, scroll to the position saved in the cookie.
    if ( $.cookie("scroll") !== null ) {
        $(".yourTableContainerDIV").scrollTop( $.cookie("scroll") );
    }

    // On window unload, save cookie
    $(window).unload(function() {
        $.cookie("scroll", $(".yourTableContainerDIV").scrollTop() );
    });
});
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744145/how-to-remember-scroll-position-o-page/12744617#12744617), with a few tiny modifications.

**EDIT:**

So it doesn't quite work.

The first problem is that if you're using [this table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043837/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header), it isn't the container DIV's `scrollTop` that you need to read, it's the tbody that you need to look at.

And the second problem is that the value of `$(".scrollContent").scrollTop()` becomes 0 before `$(window).unload()` is called. When I modify the code like this:

```
// When document is ready...
$(document).ready(function() {

    // If cookie is set, scroll to the position saved in the cookie.
    if ( $.cookie("scroll") !== null ) {
        $(".yourTableContainerDIV").scrollTop( $.cookie("scroll") );
    }

    // Set i to the current scroll position every 100 milliseconds.
    var i;
    window.setInterval(function(){i=$(".scrollContent").scrollTop()}, 100);

    // On window unload, save cookie.
    $(window).unload(function() {
        $.cookie("scroll", i);
    });
});
```

it works great! But then you've got a function being called and a value being set every tenth of a second, which isn't too good for performance. An alternative is to use `window.beforeUnload` like so:

```
// When document is ready...
$(document).ready(function() {
    // If cookie is set, scroll to the position saved in the cookie.
    if ( $.cookie("scroll") !== null ) {
        $(".yourTableContainerDIV").scrollTop( $.cookie("scroll") );
    }
});

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    $.cookie("scroll", $(".scrollContent").scrollTop());
    return;
}
```

which works great in most browsers and doesn't involve intervals, but it doesn't work in Opera.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I put that at the beginning of my document in the <body> section... Downloaded jQuery cookie plugin, but it still doesn´t work :/ Am I missing something?

Comment: And of course I renamed ".yourTableContainerDIV" to id of my div, ".tableContainer" (I added that later, its not in my original question)

Comment: Hmm... If you're using [this table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043837/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header), I got the `.yourTableContainerDIV` bit wrong, it should be `.scrollContent` (the tbody). And, for some reason, the value is set to 0 before the `$(window).unload` method is called. If I add `var i;window.setInterval(function(){i=$(".scrollContent").scrollTop()}, 100);` before `$(window).unload` and change `$.cookie("scroll", $(".yourTableContainerDIV").scrollTop() );` to `$.cookie("scroll", i);`, it works great, but you've got a function being called every tenth of a second.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the code works for me...Is it possible I need to include something in the code to make this work? The script itself seems simple enough so I don´t think its wrongly implemented...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 100% working solution for persistent table scroll position for anyone who needs it.

```
    // save position of table scroll
    $(function () {
        // If cookie is set, scroll to the position saved in the cookie.
        if ($.cookie("scroll") !== null) {
            $('#bScroll').scrollTop($.cookie("scroll"));
        }
    });

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        $.cookie("scroll", $('#bScroll').scrollTop());
        return;
    }
```

Set tbody id='bScroll' and you are good to go.

Simple and guaranteed without fail. There are many 'solutions' out there but none worked for me except this one.